# 415--Unsupported Media Type in Spring

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am getting unsupported mediatype error.
My User Profile class looks like this

```
Class UserProfile{
private int age;
private String name,
private String currenecy;
}
```

And this is the method in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Create", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<UserProfileResponse> createUserProfile(@RequestBody UserProfile userProfile)
{
UserProfileResponse userProfileResponse = new UserProfileResponse();
int id = createUserProfileData(userProfile)
userProfileResponse.setId(id);
return new ResponseEntity<UserProfileResponse>(userProfileResponse,HTTPStatus.OK);
}
```

I am trying to send the request through POSTMAN but getting 
Error 415--Unsupported Media Type
My Request in POstman looks like this

```
Content-Type:application/json
Accept:application/json 
Method is : POST
{
"age":28,
"name":"Sam",
"currency": "INR"
}
```

[image]

Suggest me what I am missing?

Comment: Can you please post your  context.xml ?

Comment: are you using jackson in your classpath? if yes, is that correctly configed ?

Comment: try using `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` instead of `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after after spending some time.. I figured out why it was not working.
In my java based spring configuration file I missed "@EnableWebMvc".
After adding  it, my problem got resolved.

```
@Configuration
**@EnableWebMvc**   // This annotation was missing.
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.hemant.*")
public class TestConfiguration  {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to select "JSON" format, filled in arbitrary JSON string in the textarea.

Also use either Accept or Content-type at a time.

If that doesn't work then can you check like below by removing consumes and adding headers manually.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Create", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but no luck

Comment: Added POSTMAN sceenshot

Comment: @hemantmali Can you please post your complete controller and `createUserProfileData(userProfile)` method also

Comment: can you remove one of them and check from Accept and Content-type

Answer (score 0):

I could see the response coming back with your code. I am deliberately returning the same object just to test the connectivity. Following is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method= RequestMethod.POST,consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<UserProfile> createUserProfile(@RequestBody UserProfile userProfile)
{
    System.out.println("Got request");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userProfile, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Used getter and setter in UserProfile

```
public class UserProfile {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private String currenecy;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCurrenecy() {
        return currenecy;
    }

    public void setCurrenecy(String currenecy) {
        this.currenecy = currenecy;
    }
}
```