# Spring app returning HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm making SpringMVC webapp. I have a Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value ="/certificate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class GiftCertificateController {
    private final GiftCertificateService gcs;
    
    @Autowired
    public GiftCertificateController(GiftCertificateService gcs) {
        this.gcs = gcs;
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> createCertificate(@RequestBody GiftCertificate gc) throws Exception {
        gcs.createCertificate(gc);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Map.of("status", HttpStatus.CREATED), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    
    // some GetMapping and DeleteMapping functions
    // omitted for simplicity
}
```

And I am trying to make a POST in Postman to create a certificate with JSON:

```json
{
    "name": "sas",
    "description": "sasasas",
    "price": 12,
    "duration": 12
}
```

I tried to change my Content-type to application/json, but it still isn't work.

Comment: Please include relevant code/config as code-formatted text in the question itself.

Comment: what exactly is your `Content-Type`? It needs to be `application/json`.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Please don't paste links to [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Please edit your code to match the [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking a good question.  Feel free to peruse the site to get a better idea of other's questions, and also search the site to ensure your question isn't a duplicate of a question someone else has asked previously.

Comment: I've already changed the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is not being handled by your controller. HTTP 415 means "Unsupported Media Type".

> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format.
>
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the data directly.

Try adding the **header `"Content-Type"`** with value `"application/json"` to your postman request.

The search engine in Stack Overflow is quite powerful. These questions might also provide helpful info:

- [POST JSON fails with 415 Unsupported media type, Spring 3 mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc?rq=1)
- [Http 415 Unsupported Media type error with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json?rq=1)
- [415--Unsupported Media Type in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316147/415-unsupported-media-type-in-spring?rq=1)

Comment: I already have that Content-Type

Comment: But in response I have txt

Answer (score 0):

​​The error 415-The unsupported file format error occurs when server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format of file type.

1.Ensure that you are sending the proper Content-Type header value.

2.Verify that your server is able to process the value defined in the **Content-Type header**.

3.Check the Accept header to verify what the server is actually willing to process.

- To resolve this issue, explicitly set the content type under the request headers as **Post**
- Make sure to change body **"Text" to "JSON"**

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the issue  even after changing the Content-type to application/JSON

- to resolve it I have created a DTO to take the input from the JSON file
- and then passed the values to the entity object through the DTO

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).